# how to select a security-group id for the source when creating a security group in AWS with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

In the AWS console when you are creating a security group you can select a security group ID for the source IP (inbound rule). Is it possible to do this in terraform, and if so how would you do this?

[image: AWS Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `aws_security_group_rule` described here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule
It has a `source_security_group_id` field where you can specify the security group you want to allow traffic from.

Before that you'd probably create the security group with the `aws_security_group`  resource https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group.
And you can the pass the id of this security group in the `security_group_id` field of the `aws_security_group_rule` resource.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have given this a try but I am getting an error, but I will raise another question for that

Comment: Ignore me, the error was a typo. Thanks for your help again!